# Using select() for socket programming. Problems with FD_ISSET

Tags: c, select

I'm trying to receive a message from a server but I have some problems. I'm sure that my server code is good because it worked without multiplexing sockets but right now when I'm trying to use select() it doesn't receive anything.

```
while(1){
    tmp_fds = read_fds;
if (select(fdmax + 1, &tmp_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
          error((char *)"ERROR in select");
if (FD_ISSET (sockfd, &tmp_fds)){
  memset(buffer, 0 , BUFLEN);
  n = recv (sockfd,buffer,BUFLEN,0);
}
```

This is my code for receiving from the server. What am I doing wrong ? 
The socket which is used to comunicate with the server is already in read_fds.
BUFLEN is 256.

Comment: Is the FD_ISSET block being executed? What's the value of 'n'? And what's the memset() for? You don't need it.

Comment: Before select, FD_ISSET is true. After that select, FD_ISSET is false. I don't understand why. I can't print the value of 'n' because the code doesn't get executed in that if statement.

Comment: Please reformat your code to use consistent indentation. If you don't, you won't receive as much help because people will look at your code, think "*Oh, where art thou a gibbering mess of dribble?*" and move on to the next question.

Comment: Is `sockfd` the only fd that's set in `read_fds`? If not, some other fd may be readable, but you're not checking for it.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour If we ignored all the poorly-indented questions, we'd have hardly anything to do....

Comment: Why does your `error()` function require a character string argument ot be cast? But it would be better to use `perror()`, so that the reason for the error will be displayed.

Comment: @Barmar Fair point. `s/refactor/reformat/`. If we don't encourage people to indent their code properly, then we're consenting to the diminishing of code legibility. Contrary to your belief, people *will* correct their indentation, and we *will* have something *readable* to focus on. If they want help, they'll go out of their way to get help.

Comment: @Barmar : no. I use stdin and other fd for client - client communication.

Comment: Then after `select()` returns, you need to check each of those fd's to see if they're set.

Comment: Well, stdin works and i suppose that all the others fd's are working. The problem is after select. Select() returns 1 or -1. In my case select() return 1, but after using it, when i verify `if (FD_ISSET (sockfd, &tmp_fds))` this returns 0. It should return 1.

Comment: If `select()` returns 1, it means one of the fd's in `tmp_fds` is ready to read. But it could be one of the other ones beside `sockfd`. You don't know which until you check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
while(1)
{
    tmp_fds = read_fds;
    int ret=select(fdmax + 1, &tmp_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret > 0)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET (sockfd, &tmp_fds))
        {
            // there is no need for the memset
            memset(buffer, 0 , BUFLEN);
            n = recv (sockfd,buffer,BUFLEN,0);
        }
    }
    else
        if (ret < 0) 
        {
           error((char *)"ERROR in select");
           // here you must check what kind of error you received
           // may be you need to close the socket and start over again
           // return;
        }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. With this code i can't even write something to stdin. This `if (FD_ISSET (sockfd, &tmp_fds))` is still false :(

Comment: For the sake of improving this answer, I would suggest that there is some reason behind using `memset` prior to `recv`. Perhaps the OP wants to pass a *string*, derived from `buffer`, to a *string handling* function. In order for that to happen, there needs to be a guarantee that there's a `'\0'` at the end (and currently, there still is no such guarantee). `memset` is excessive for that purposes; I know, and you know this. Understanding the reason, providing an alternative, and at the same time explaining how this code causes string-handling violations might make this answer *excellent*.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour right now, the problem is not memset(). the problem is that FD_ISSET returns 0 after using select().

Comment: @Matei I understand that, but suggesting that it isn't necessary without providing an alternative might be more harmful than helpful. Why even mention it, when that's not the issue? You've covered the issue, and you *could* cover `memset` at the end of the answer, but that's your choice. I won't say any more...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour well, what should i do ?

Comment: @Matei Is string handling a requirement of your problem? If so, I'd suggest recieving `BUFLEN - 1` bytes, so that you can guarantee space for a `'\0'` even when the maximum number of bytes has been recieved. Check `n` to see if it's negative; If so, handle the error, otherwise use `n` to determine where the `'\0'` should go: `if (n < 0) { perror("recv"); buffer[0] = '\0'; } else { buffer[n] = '\0'; }`... Now you don't need `memset`!

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Thank you for pointing that out, I should have explained it rather than saying NOT USE IT.

Comment: @ja_mesa Well, I did say "... explaining how this code causes string-handling violations might make this answer *excellent*."

Answer (score 0):

Before calling select, you should clear the FD structure and set the flags you need. After all, when select returns, the bits might be changed from select and when you next time execute the loop they are different than before.

Here is the example that I use for my server that I'm currently implement and this works for sure.

```
while(sigterm == false)
{
    FD_ZERO(&mReaders);
    FD_ZERO(&mWriters);
    FD_ZERO(&mExceptions);

    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &mReaders);
    FD_SET(serversocket, &mReaders);
    pret = pselect(FD_SETSIZE, &mReaders, &mWriters, &mExceptions, NULL, &mSignalMask);
    nErrorCode _code = errno;
    if(pret == 0)
    {
        // Timeout occured, but we are not interested in that for now.
        continue;
    }

    if(pret < 0)
    {
        switch(nErrorCode)
        {
            case EINTR:
                cout << "Interrupted: " << pret << "   errno: " << nErrorCode << endl;
            break;

            default:
            {
                cout << "Unknown retval from pselect: " << pret<< "   errno: " << nErrorCode << endl;
            }
        }
        continue;
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &mReaders))
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        cout << "stdin: " << s << endl;
        continue;
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(serversocket, &mReaders))
    {
        // client connected
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a good answer to a similar C++ question... but I'm fairly sure, to the contrary, that this code *absolutely doesn't* work in C.

Comment: Change cout to printf and it turns magically into C. Really! *sigh*

Comment: I am clearing the FD structure. That's my big problem. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm using this code and it works. So what exaclty is your problem? Print the returnvalue and errno right after select and see what it is returning. That might give you a hint what is going on in your code.

Comment: If i print `sockfd` the result is 3. That means that my client listens on socket number 3, right ?

Comment: No. AFAIK it means that three descriptors in your select call will not block. select returns the total number of non blocking descriptors, not the descriptor that caused it, because there can be more than one. You might also consider using pselect instead of select.

Comment: @Devolus This is my code when I'm setting the file descriptors before while : 
    `FD_SET(listen_sockfd, &read_fds);`
    `fdmax = listen_sockfd;`
    `FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &read_fds);`
    `FD_SET(sockfd, &read_fds);`

Comment: Matei, you should not print sockfd, but the return value from select.

Comment: Did you also do a FD_ZERO before FD_SET?

Comment: @Devolus the return value from select is 1. :) the return value from FD_ISSET (sockfd, &tmp_fds) is 0.
Yes, i did a FD_ZERO before FD_SET.

Comment: Oh my GOD ! fdmax should be equal to sockfd. That's the problem ! I don't use listen_sockfd anywhere right now. I solved the problem. thank you guys !